# How can I calculate the phasors?

Tags: phasor

For example, there are three values.

$$X_1 = \frac{1}{250\angle16.26^\circ} \quad X_2=\frac{1}{200\angle -36.87^\circ} \quad X_3=\frac{1}{50\angle -53.13^\circ}$$

Then, I want to calculate \$X_1+X_2+X_3\$.

---

I can solve this by the following process.

1. Change \$X_1\$, \$X_2\$, and \$X_3\$ into the form of \$A+jB\$, resepctively.
2. Add respective real part and imaginary part.
3. Re change into the phasor form.

---

However, I trust that there exist another easy way to solve it rather than my process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 2 way that I see you can resolve this.

1. If you don't have acess to a calculator that can do complex number, well first you need to do the division. The easiest way to do that is to use polar notation. After that you transform each X into cartesian form to add them up.
2. If you have access to do a calculator who can do complex number, just use the complex function of your calculator, you will save a lot of time.